# Error while using TTF_RENDERGLYPH_SOLID

Tags: sdl, pascal

This short program in PASCAL should display a simple text, but instead i got an error:
"Project  My Application raised exception class External SIGSEGV at address 71002A95"

```
PROGRAM chap5;

USES SDL,SDL_TTF;

VAR  
screen, fontface:pSDL_SURFACE;   
loaded_font:pointer;  
colour_font, colour_font2:pSDL_COLOR;   
i:BYTE;  

BEGIN  
SDL_INIT(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);  
screen:=SDL_SETVIDEOMODE(400,200,32,SDL_SWSURFACE);  
IF screen=NIL THEN HALT;  


IF TTF_INIT=-1 THEN HALT;  
loaded_font:=TTF_OPENFONT('C:\Windows\Fonts\Arial\ariblk.ttf',5);  

NEW(colour_font);  
NEW(colour_font2);  
colour_font^.r:=255;   colour_font^.g:=0;      colour_font^.b:=0;  
colour_font2^.r:=0;    colour_font2^.g:=255;   colour_font2^.b:=255;

fontface:=TTF_RENDERTEXT_SHADED(loaded_font,'HELLO',colour_font^,colour_font2^);  

SDL_BLITSURFACE(fontface,NIL,screen,NIL);  
SDL_FLIP(screen);  
READLN;  

DISPOSE(colour_font);  
DISPOSE(colour_font2);  
SDL_FREESURFACE(screen);  
SDL_FREESURFACE(fontface);  
TTF_CLOSEFONT(loaded_font);  
TTF_QUIT;  
SDL_QUIT;  
END.
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: Step through it in a debugger. What line is causing the problem? There are several places where you do no error checking of function calls in your code, and clearly one of them is failing and causing the problem. We can't tell which one it is, so you'll need to do so.

Comment: if i take this line in commas       fontface:=TTF_RENDERTEXT_SHADED(loaded_font,'HELLO',colour_font^,colour_font2^);     program runs (of course it dont display text)

Comment: Then clearly there's either no `loaded_font` value returned by `TTF_OPENFONT`, or there's something wrong with the way you're passing the two `pSDL_COLOR` values. It's probably the latter - I don't think you need the `^`; they're pointers, and the function expects pointers.

Comment: yes, i checked and TTF_OPENFONT returns NIL... but then again - why? the path is correct

Comment: I don't know, because I'm not sitting at your machine. :-) I don't have the file on my Windows 7 machine in that location. Are you sure the path is 100% right? What happens if you try to list that file at a command prompt using `dir "C:\Windows\Fonts\Arial\ariblk.ttf`? If I do it on my machine, I get "The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: so what is your patch?

Comment: What "patch"? I've already said I can't tell what's wrong, because I'm not at your machine. If you're asking me where the file is, it doesn't matter - find it on **your machine**. Windows Explorer is quite good at searching for things, and where it is located on my machine won't fix your code. I'd suspect it's in the `Windows\Fonts` folder, not the `Windows\Fonts\Arial` folder, though.

Comment: i downloaded a new font, wrote loaded_font:=TTF_OPENFONT('C:\Users\User\Downloads\Alabama.ttf',12); and now the error is "Project My Application raised exception class External SIGSEGV at address 68122A84"

Comment: So do what I told you in the first place: **step through the code in the debugger**, and figure out what's going wrong. **I can't dd that for you**.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to load a font that isn't in the location you think it is, and therefore `TTF_OPENFONT` is returning nil. You then do no error checking of the return value, and just blindly use `loaded_font` with an invalid value in the rest of your code.

On my Windows 7 system, the font is located in `C:\Windows\Fonts\ariblk.ttf`; note there is no `Arial` folder in that pathname.

You need to actually check the return values of any function calls, particularly those made to an external API, in order to make sure they succeeded. You also need to check to make sure the file is in the location you think it is before loading it.

```
const
  FontFileName = 'C:\Windows\Fonts\ariblk.ttf';
...

  if not FileExists(FontFileName) then
  begin
    WriteLn('Font file doesn't exist in ' + FontFileName);
    Halt;
  end;

  loaded_font := TTF_OPENFONT(FontFileName, 5);  
  if loaded_font = nil then
  begin
    WriteLn('TTF_OPENFONT failed!');
    Halt;
  end;

  // Other code here - check the return values of the SDL functions!
```

You also have a couple of other problems:

First, you've declared the two variables (`colour_font' and`colour_font2`incorrectly. They shouldn't be pointers, but just references to`TSDK_Color` instead:

```
colour_font, colour_font2: TSDL_Color;
```

Now you no longer need the two calls to `New` and `Dispose`, so remove them completely.

Change your code to

```
colour_font.r := 255;
colour_font.g := 0;
colour_font.b := 0;

colour_font2.r := 0;
colour_font2.g := 255;
colour_font2.b := 255;

fontface :=TTF_RENDERTEXT_SHADED(loaded_font, 
                                 'HELLO',
                                 colour_font,   // Remove ^ - no longer needed
                                 colour_font2);
```

Once again, **check the return values of all function calls** before using the value returned.

Comment: ok i did it, i put C:\Windows\Fonts\ariblk.ttf and all those if's and the program runs but still doesnt display a text, just black a window. And after being closed i get ""Project My Application raised exception class External SIGSEGV at address 68122A84""

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't write or debug your entire program for you. As I've said twice before, you need to **use the debugger** to step through the code.

Comment: without "^" :  Error:Incompatible for arg. no 4: Got "PSDL_Color" expected "TSDL_Color"

Comment: i use Lazarus IDE v.1.0.1.2

Comment: Then you've declared the variables wrong in the first place as `PSDL_Color` (I just used what you provided - I don't have the source or library files here). Fix the variable declarations to properly declare them as `TSDL_Color`, remove the two calls to `NEW()` that you don't need, and remove the `^` everywhere else. Use `F5` to set a breakpoint where you want to start debugging, and run your app. When the debugger stops, use `F8` to execute each line of code. Use watchpoints to examine the content of variables. I can't give you any more of a debugger tutorial in a comment here.

Comment: See the [Lazarus docs](http://wiki.freepascal.org/GDB_Debugger_Tips) regarding using the debugger; there's a [separate page](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Debugger_Console_App) for debugging console apps like yours.

Comment: Read what I wrote: **remove the ^ everywhere else**. Take out the `^`, because you don't need them. This is silly. I cannot teach you to write code or work the debugger here. I've taken you as far as I can in this space. Good luck.

Comment: "^" removed. But still SIGSEGV at address 68122A84. Goodbye